# Problem loading images from object file in react

Tags: reactjs, image, object

I have an object file and can't seem to get the images to load from that file, if I do an import in the index file and call it, the images load and work fine but if I try it from the object file then it doesn't work. I'm not getting any errors in the console and have tried listing the images from different locations.

Here's the object file

```
export const projects = [
  {
    id: "0",
    image: "../../images/mayhemds.png",
    alt: "TelecomPlus",
    title: "TelecomPlus",
    desc: "Built the TelecomPlus website on the Apostrophe CMS, using the tech stack listed below.",
    tags: ["HTML", "JavaScript", "SCSS", "Apostrophe CMS"],
    source: "https://google.com",
    visit: "https://goggle.com",
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    image: "/public/data_trend.png",
    alt: "telecomplus",
    title: "Project 2",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.",
    tags: ["Html", "JavaScript", "SCSS", "Nunjucks", "Git"],
    source: "https://google.com",
    visit: "https://goggle.com",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    image: "../../images/telecomplus.png",
    alt: "telecomplus",
    title: "Project 3",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.",
    tags: ["Html", "JavaScript", "SCSS", "Nunjucks", "Git"],
    source: "https://google.com",
    visit: "https://goggle.com",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    image: "../../images/telecomplus.png",
    alt: "telecomplus",
    title: "Project 4",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.",
    tags: ["Html", "JavaScript", "SCSS", "Nunjucks", "Git"],
    source: "https://google.com",
    visit: "https://goggle.com",
  },
];
```

Here is the index.js file

```
import { projects } from "./projects";
import "./projects.css";

const Projects = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="project-section" id="projects">
        <div className="project-container">
            <h2 className="project-heading">Projects</h2>
          <div className="card-wrap">
            {projects.map(
              ({ id, image, title, desc, tags, source, visit, alt }) => (
                <div className="project-card" key={id}>
                  <img className="project-image" src={image} alt={alt} />
                  <h3 className="title">{title}</h3>
                  <p className="desc">{desc}</p>
                  <div className="stack">
                    <h4 className="stackTitle">Stack</h4>
                    <ul className="tag-list">
                      {tags.map((tag, i) => (
                        <li className="tag-list-item" key={i}>
                          {tag}
                        </li>
                      ))}
                    </ul>

                    <div className="btn-wrap">
                      <div className="btn" href={source}>
                        Code
                      </div>
                      <div className="btn" href={visit}>
                        Website
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```

I can't seem to see what's missing. Any help would be truly grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your files `public` folder, you need to let webpack include it in the bundle, therefore you should use `import` / `require` with its path:

```
// image === "../../images/mayhemds.png"
<img className="project-image" src={require(image)} alt={alt} />
```

It explained in CRA [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/).

Comment: So Are you saying I can't do it from an object file?

Comment: there is no such file "../../images/mayhemds.png" after bundling, you need to specify it, see examples in docs